# How to send two parameters in a partial model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In addition to the model itself, I want to pass the product id in the partial model. How to do this?

```
@Model.product.id
<partial name="_Score" model="@Model.rating"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Create a class and add two properties example like below
```

`   public class Your_Class_Name{
public int CaseId
{
get;set;
}
public string PatientName
{
get;set;
}

```
//and call your partial view like
@Html.Partial("PartialPatientHeaderDetails", new YourClassName
{
  CaseId= @Model.CaseId,PatientName= @havePatientName })
//finally change your return mode in partial View
@model Your_Class_Name 
@{

 }
```

@Model.CaseId

@Model.PatientName